# how to get linked image url in component using generate index data tbb - Field Mapping

Tags: sites-9.1, tbb, elasticsearch

i am trying to integrate elastic search in tridion 9.1
web application is in dxa 2.2.
i want to use field mapping parameter schema field present in generate index metadata TBB
[image]

Currently it is returning only image tcm short id. i.e
in component source image node is as follows:
[image]

and in add index data section i am getting image id as 1472. instead of short tcm id i am looking for image url and xlink title.

can anybody help me with that?

Comment: To help with your question, could you please share the other TBBs in the template and confirm where the markup you're showing is coming from (in Template Builder, CM preview, in delivery, DXA, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinReyes: Markups are showing in template builder and as well as under CM preview source tab when try to preview the dynamic component.